# check two session variable in if statement in php

Tags: php, session, authentication

I want to allow login using facebook and google in php.

I have two session variables one for facebook login and another for google.
But only one is working in if statement i want to check both with OR (||)

My code is

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userDataFacebook']) OR !isset($_SESSION['userDataGoogle']))
{
echo "<p>You need to login to continue</p>";
else{
echo "Login";
}
```

Comment: Use `AND` not `OR` since this is only a failure of both are not set

Comment: getting in the habit of accepting answers will get you further ;-)

Comment: You have asked a lot of question and have yet to accept any answers. This site goes both ways. If you expect help you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer. Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and start giving back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user can login with either facebook or google,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userDataFacebook']) OR isset($_SESSION['userDataGoogle']))
{
  echo "Login";
else{
echo "<p>You need to login to continue</p>";
}
```

In the above case it would be helpful if you log which method user had used

If you want user to login using both facebook and google at the same time, then use `AND`

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['userDataFacebook']) AND ($_SESSION['userDataGoogle']))
    {
   echo "login";
    else{
     echo "<p>You need to login to continue</p>";
    }
```